# Is there an ARM template solution to create OMS alerts for Log analytics

Tags: azure, logging, automation, azure-rm-template, azure-log-analytics

I am trying to create an oms workspace with alerts attached to it through ARM templates.
I already created an OMS workspace and for the alert part I followed the following [tutorial](https://abcdazure.azurewebsites.net/how-to-deploy-oms-alerts-with-arm-template/).
After some struggle why my alert won't deploy i saw in the commands of the same tuturial following note.

The "Action" scheme has been changed and additionally the alerts are in the Azure Monitor:) Here is [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/azure-monitor/insights/solutions-resources-searches-alerts#actions).

When I tried to read the documentation and get any smarter I just got stuck in a endless loop of reference links:

The link provided in the tutorial said that `Beginning May 14, 2018, all alerts in an Azure public cloud instance of Log Analytics workspace began to extend into Azure.` After some Time I found following [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-create-action-group-with-resource-manager-template). Where I thought I finnaly found how the new alert will be explained. But this is for application insights not for log analytics.

TO my question than: Is there someone who can help me out try to find how the new Alert scheme works or try to guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an OMS expert, but this is what we've been using:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2017-03-15-preview",
    "name": "[concat(variables('namespace'), '/', variables('savedSearches').Search[copyIndex()].Name)]",
    "type": "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/savedSearches",
    "copy": {
        "name": "SavedSearchCopy",
        "count": "[length(variables('savedSearches').Search)]"
    },
    "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/', variables('namespace'))]",
        "ActionGroupCopy"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "category": "Alerts",
        "displayName": "[variables('savedSearches').Search[copyIndex()].DisplayName]",
        "query": "[variables('savedSearches').Search[copyIndex()].Query]"
    }
},
{
    "name": "[tolower(concat(variables('namespace'), '/', variables('savedSearches').Search[copyIndex()].Name, '/',  variables('savedSearches').Search[copyIndex()].Schedule.Name))]",
    "type": "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/savedSearches/schedules/",
    "apiVersion": "2017-03-03-preview",
    "copy": {
        "name": "ScheduleCopy",
        "count": "[length(variables('savedSearches').Search)]"
    },
    "dependsOn": [
        "SavedSearchCopy"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "interval": "5",
        "queryTimeSpan": "10",
        "enabled": true
    }
},
{
    "name": "[tolower(concat(variables('namespace'), '/', variables('savedSearches').Search[copyIndex()].Name, '/',  variables('savedSearches').Search[copyIndex()].Schedule.Name, '/', variables('savedSearches').Search[copyIndex()].Alert.Name, '-', if(contains(variables('savedSearches').Search[copyIndex()].Alert, 'MetricsTrigger'), 'Total', 'Consecutive')))]",
    "type": "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/savedSearches/schedules/actions",
    "copy": {
        "name": "ActionCopy",
        "count": "[length(variables('savedSearches').Search)]"
    },
    "apiVersion": "2017-03-15-preview",
    "dependsOn": [
        "SavedSearchCopy"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "Type": "Alert",
        "Name": "[variables('savedSearches').Search[copyIndex()].Alert.Name]",
        "Description": "[variables('savedSearches').Search[copyIndex()].Alert.Description]",
        "Severity": "warning",
        "Threshold": "[variables('savedSearches').Search[copyIndex()].Alert.Threshold]",
        "Throttling": {
            "DurationInMinutes": 60
        },
        "AzNsNotification": {
            "GroupIds": [
                "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/actionGroups', 'xxx')]"
            ]
        }
    }
},
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Insights/actionGroups",
    "apiVersion": "2018-03-01",
    "name": "[variables('actionGroups')[copyIndex()].Name]",
    "copy": {
        "name": "ActionGroupCopy",
        "count": "[length(variables('actionGroups'))]"
    },
    "location": "Global",
    "properties": {
        "groupShortName": "[variables('actionGroups')[copyIndex()].Name]",
        "enabled": true,
        "emailReceivers": [
            {
                "name": "[variables('actionGroups')[copyIndex()].EmailName]",
                "emailAddress": "[variables('actionGroups')[copyIndex()].EmailAddress]"
            }
        ]
    }
},
```

here is a sample saved search variable which we use to map everything:

```
"savedSearches": {
    "Search": [
        {
            "Name": "HighCPU",
            "DisplayName": "CPU Above 90%",
            "Query": "Perf | where CounterName == \"% Processor Time\" and InstanceName ==\"_Total\" | summarize AggregatedValue = avg(CounterValue) by Computer, bin(TimeGenerated, 1m)",
            "Schedule": {
                "Name": "HighCPUSchedule"
            },
            "Alert": {
                "Name": "HighCPUAlert",
                "Description": "Alert for High CPU",
                "Threshold": {
                    "Operator": "gt",
                    "Value": 90,
                    "MetricsTrigger": {
                        "Value": 2,
                        "Operator": "gt",
                        "TriggerCondition": "Consecutive"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```